# what grammar is "if separate species we be"?

Tags: sentence-construction

> Science will perhaps be the ultimate exterminator of our human species—**if separate species we be**—for its reserve of unguessed horrors could never be borne.

I am wondering what grammar is the "if" in the sentence. Is it a parenthesis? And it seems to omit "should", why? It doesn't seem like a subjunctive clause to me because there is a "will". Also the predicative word is put forward. I am very confused. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"—if separate species we be—" is a [parenthetic clause.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parenthesis_(rhetoric)) (In this case the punctuation used is not actual parentheses but em-dashes.) The subjunctive mood used (the `if`) is a fancy construction; the meaning of the clause is: "If indeed we actually are a separate species."

The passage might be rewritten:

> Assuming "human beings" are actually a separate species [from other humanoids, animals, etc], science might be the eventual downfall of our species. This is because we will not be able to survive the unforeseen bad things science might discover.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fancy version of saying *If we attempt to be species we aren't supposed to be, science will exterminate us.*(for whatever reasons!)

The writer has employed the *subjunctive* here. In nutshell, this is one of the three *moods* of the English grammar and is used to express wishes, hypothetical situations (as  in your example), etc.